# Embedded UIWebView YouTube Volume

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I'm working on an iOS app that can display YouTube videos in a UIWebView.  Everything is working great except...

The first time a video is played it plays at ~10% volume.  The device volume is set at 100% and the player volume shows 100% in the UI.  Backing out of the web view and play a song in the app using our native streaming player then go back to the video it plays at the correct volume.

Things that don't work...

---

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0];
}
```

---

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0];
}
```

Both calls just flash the volume changed UI on screen and do nothing for the WebView volume.

If you have any ideas that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use JavaScript injection.

Comment: Use JavaScript injection to do what?

Comment: to decrease the volume of the YouTube player in the web page.

Comment: Playing at 100% volume according to the player.  But its really only playing at ~10%.

Comment: Also there isn't a Javascript api that I know of for the MPMoviePlayer the webview creates to playback the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I just needed to set the playback type back from the built in audio player.

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
BOOL ok;
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
ok = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
```

Something along those lines.